# What is the fastest way to extract data from database (Oracle) to a local file

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I got connection to Oracle DB (IP, username, password, sid etc.) and need to connect to DB and extract all records from one table (700K records) into a local file.

What is the fastest way (function/library) to do that using Python?

(This task will be scheduled to execute every so often and performance - number of records per second is very important. There is no way - permissions to ssh-connect to a linux server where oracle resides directly and run some sqlplus script or similar)

File will be later used to upload local (MySql database with similar table).

Original Oracle database is used by other team and is not suppose to be hit more than once every so often and will have frequent changes. We need to capture (every so often) changes and then do some changes (updates) on a record level in internal mysql db.

Open for suggestions..

Comment: It's likely any of the db modules will be sufficiently fast to not be the bottleneck - the real questions are things like 'what kind of file? Is it for reading,, writing and sending back, backup? What is the total data size? How much RAM/disk IO do you have? What is your network bandwidth/latency?

Comment: why? the data is in the database, and easily retrieved from there. Build your python app to read the data on demand, don't extract it to some file that needs maintained.

Comment: also you just said you have connection to connect to db, and then you say there's no way to do it...so which one is it?

Comment: The fastest way is, I guess, the *original* EXP utility. You have a way to connect to the database, file will reside on your computer (that's a "local file", right?), but - what do you plan to do with it? DMP file (which is the result of the export utility) isn't *readable*, but you can import it into another database. I think that it would be easier to answer if you described what's the purpose of doing it.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith (I was referring to ssh connect to a server - edited).

Comment: Updated with more info as for more help.

Comment: the fastest way would be to keep the data  in the database

Comment: I'd say you need to get the 'other team' to play ball and let you have access. or worst case, replicate the changes auto-magically to your mysql db. There are software solutions for that.

Comment: Given that Jeff’s answer is the fastest, the second fastest would be not to us python ;)

Comment: If you insist on copying the data to a local DB, make it a local Oracle DB and connect to the source DB via a DB link to get the data.  I.e don't move the data to disk and then back into a DB.

Comment: I am not insisting on anything - it is just hard to change requirements from my side. How would I make a link to connect to other Oracle and transfer data?

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793 and then google or ask on asktom.oracle.com